# Inconsistent Code Returns from Different Android Devices

Tags: android

I am using the code below to return my numbers with the proper notation that a locale uses.  For example, European formatting uses a comma rather than a decimal displaying floats/doubles. While testing on devices this code works, but not on a Droid X (so I wonder how many other phones this may occur on also).  Has anyone run into this and/or may have a solution?

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * <p>Converts doubles to twoDecimal points with proper notation per locale</p>
 * 
 * @param double 
 * @return converted number to 2 decimal points with proper notation 
 */
public static String getFormattedValue(double d) {
    Locale mLocale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;

    String formattedString;
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(mLocale);
    DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
    df.applyPattern("###,###.##");

    formattedString = df.format(d);

    return formattedString;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "[the code does not work] on a Droid X?" What is `mLocale` when the code works vs "does not work?"

Comment: On Droid X, if I have the phone language set to Spanish, the code above does not return the proper notation for numbers (commas not decimals). Outside of my application the phone does not utilize the comma rather than the decimal as seen if I go into "settings" and look at application sizes.  Nexus 1 displays the comma rather than the decimal in both instances.  I will update my post and include images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I figured it out. If my phone's locale (language) is set to Spanish and displays decimals, then the locale is actually Spanish (United States).  If it displays commas, then it is European Spanish.  My Droid X list English or Spanish, whereas the Nexus 1 has Espanol( Espana) and Espanol(Estados Unidos).